# Common Lisp: Any way to avoid defvar or defparameter?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm using *SBCL 2.0.1.debian* and Paul Graham's *ANSI Common Lisp* to learn Lisp.

Right in Chapter 2 though, I'm realizing that I cannot use `setf` like the author can! A little googling and I learn that I must use `defvar` or `defparameter` to 'introduce' my globals before I can set them with `setq`!

Is there any way to avoid having to introduce globals via the `defvar` or `defparameter`, either from inside SBCL or from outside via switches? Do other Lisp's too mandate this?

I understand their value-add in large codebases but right now I'm just learning by writing smallish programs, and so am finding them cumbersome. I'm used to using globals in other languages, so don't necessarily mind global- / local-variable bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing programs, in the sense of things which have some persistent existence in files, then use the `def*` forms.  Top-level `setf` / `setq` of an undefined variable has undefined semantics in CL and, even worse, has differing semantics across implementations.  Typing `defvar`, `defparameter` or `defconstant` is not much harder than typing `setf` or `setq` and means your programs will have defined semantics, which is usually considered a good thing.  So no, for programs there is no way to avoid using the `def*` forms, or some equivalent thereof.

If you are simply typing things at a REPL / listener to play with things, then I think just using `setf` at top-level is fine (no-one uses environments where things typed at the REPL are really persistent any more I think).

You say you are used to using globals in other languages.  Depending on what those other languages are this quite probably means you're *not* used to CL's semantics for bindings defined with `def*` forms, which are not only global, but *globally special*, or globally dynamic.  I don't know which other languages even have CL's special / lexical distinction, but I suspect that not that many do.  For instance consider this Python (3) program:

```py
x = 1

def foo():
    x = 0
    print(x)
    def bar():
        nonlocal x
        x += 1
        return x
    return bar

y = foo()

print(y())
print(y())
print(x)
```

If you run this it will print

```
0
1
2
1
```

So consider the 'equivalent' CL program (note: *never write a program with variables named like this*):

```
(defvar x 1)

(defun foo ()
  (let ((x 0))
    (print x)
    (lambda ()
      (incf x))))

(let ((y (foo)))
  (print (funcall y))
  (print (funcall y))
  (print x)
  (values))
```

If you run this it will print

```
0
2
3
3
```

Which I think you can agree is very different from what the Python program printed.

That's because top-level variables in CL are special, or dynamic variables: in the above CL program `x` is dynamically scoped because `x` has been declared globally special by the `defvar`, and this means that the calls to the function returned by `foo` are altering the global value of `x`.

Python doesn't have dynamic bindings at all (but you can write Python modules which will simulate them as functions which access an explicit binding stack, with a bit of deviousness).  Something like this is also how other languages expose dynamic bindings.  For instance this is how Racket does it:

```lisp
(define d (make-parameter 1))

(define (foo)
  (parameterize ([d 0])
    (display (d))
    (λ ()
      (d (+ (d) 1))
      (d))))

(let ([y (foo)])
  (display (y))
  (display (y))
  (display (d)))
```

will print

```
0
2
3
3
```

While this program

```
(define x 1)

(define (foo)
  (let ([x 0])
    (displayln x)
    (λ ()
      (set! x (+ x 1))
      x)))

(let ([y (foo)])
  (displayln (y))
  (displayln (y))
  (displayln x))
```

will print

```
0
1
2
1
```

as the Python one does.

If it wasn't for CL's compatibility requirements this is perhaps how CL should have done this too (that's obviously a personal opinion, and I'm happy with how CL *does* do it).

CL doesn't have top-level (global) *lexical* bindings at all (but you can write a CL program which will simulate them in a pretty convincing way using symbol macros).  If you want such things I suspect there are already some on the internet or I could get on and tidy up my implementation.  As an example of a program which uses such a thing:

```
(defglex x 1)

(defun foo ()
  (let ((x 0))
    (print x)
    (lambda ()
      (incf x))))

(let ((y (foo)))
  (print (funcall y))
  (print (funcall y))
  (print x))
```

will print

```
0
1
2
1
```

CL has both lexical and dynamic (special) nonglobal bindings.

As a note: the fact that things defined with the `def*` forms are *globally* special / dynamic, which means that *all* bindings of them are dynamic, is why you should always distinguish the names of such variables, using the `*` convention: `(defvar *my-var* ...)` and *never* `(defvar my-var ...)`.  (`(defconstant my-constant ...)` is OK however.)

Comment: I wonder though why the author didn't mention this when freely using `setf`. Maybe he mentions this in later chapters, which I haven't gotten to yet. Lisp encourages incremental development, and... I can't incrementally learn? Lol. Will revisit your answer as I progress through the book. Thanks.

Comment: @Harry I can't speak for Paul Graham of course and it's a long time since I read ACL (which is a good book) but I imagine that he's really describing interactions with a REPL a lot of the time, and I think using `setf` there is fine.  He may also have particular opinions that top-level `setf` *should* be fine in programs: he's not historically been a huge fan of CL I think.

Comment: CL the language doesn't have them but of course some implementations do. in CLISP, `setq` at the REPL defines a lexical variable. (just mentioning this for completeness)

Comment: Adding for completeness as well that there are no globals in CL like you might think of them coming from other languages.  There are symbols that act global in the sense that everything in their *package* can see them, but `packagea::*global*` is a completely different entity than `packageb::*global*`.